# Proper usage of controller and model mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am currently working on a mvc based project.I saw people using models n controllers in different ways,im wondering which one is the correct method according to mvc principles

Method-1:

controller:

```
  public ActionResult index()
    {
  return View();
    }

public string save ()
  {
return null;
  }

public string Update()
 {
return null;
 }
```

model:

```
 public string xx {get;set;}
   public string yy {get;set;}
```

Method-2:

controller:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
return View();
}
```

model:

```
 public string xx {get;set;}
public string yy {get;set;}

 public string save ()
      {
    return null;
      }

    public string Update()
     {
    return null;
     }
```

Comment: Method 1.  Your Save / Update Actions should be ActionResults (or similar) within the Controller, not your Model.  On Saving / Updating you would update your Model and pass that back to your View.

Comment: model should contain Properties only ?..where should i put data filling functions.in controller or  model?

Comment: You would call business logic layer from your actions in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

I would say neither is correct though method 2 is closer to it.

You should have your logic in a separate service which is consumed by your controllers.

Example:

```
public ActionResult DoStuff() {
    var model = Service.save();
    return View(model);
}

public class Model {
    public string xx { get; set; }
    public string yy { get; set; }
}

public class Service 
{
    public string save ()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string Update()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Neither the controllers or the models should have business logic in them. [They should only have a single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The model stores data that is returned by the controller. The controller simply transforms the data it receives from the service into a model.

Comment: Agree with the above.  Kinda what I was saying in my comments in your questions.  Where @GrimurD has called the class Service, that's what I'm referring to as Business Logic.

Answer (score 0):

`Method` 1.because Save /Update is `Action Method` which should be within `Controller` and not Model.

Comment: what about  functions that fills drop down menus.where should i put it?..controller or model?

Comment: Controllers are some objects, that check correspondence of user input to business-logic.